# How to call a method every minute but take into account the time it takes for that method to process might take more than one?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm working on windows service and I want to call a method from `OnStart` every minute. I originally had a forever while loop but then the service wouldn't install.

```
while (true)
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    int totalTime = 0;
    stopWatch.Start();

    MethodToCall();

    stopWatch.Stop();
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    totalTime = ts.Seconds * 1000 + ts.Milliseconds;

    if (totalTime < 60000)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(60000 - totalTime);
        //ManualResetEvent.WaitOne(10000);
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

So, how can I make my method call every minute BUT when the method exceeds one minute it will wait N number of minutes(let's say 30 seconds) and then start over by calling the method.

Comment: Are you wanting independent threads?

Comment: With or without blocking the thread?

Comment: So are you saying that if it takes 59 seconds to run, you want it to restart in the next second, but if it takes 60 seconds to run, it should wait 30 seconds before starting again?

Comment: `OnStart` is supposed to exit promptly.  Launch another thread, and put your infinite loop there.  Or use another approach, e.g., a thread pool; the details don't matter so long as `OnStart` exits promptly.

Comment: @RufusL if it takes 59 seconds then it rests a second then starts over. If it takes let's say 159 seconds, it is allowed to run as long as it takes, after than it rest for 30 seconds(or I can just tell it to start right away again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. With the `AutoReset` flag set to false, the timer will only fire once, after the specified `interval` time. In the `finally` block, we make sure to restart the timer countdown, waiting for the interval to elapse again.

```
var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer( interval.TotalMilliseconds ) { AutoReset = false };
timer.Elapsed += ( sender, eventArgs ) =>
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    try
    {
        // do work
    }
    finally
    {
        var elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
        if ( elapsed < interval )
            timer.Interval = (interval - elapsed).TotalMilliseconds;
        else
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 30 ).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Start();
    }
};
timer.Start();
```

[Source for `Timer.Elapsed` (note the bit about setting `Interval` resetting the countdown)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: With `AutoReset = false`, the Timer won't reset and will only fire once unless `Start()` is called again. It doesn't need the try/finally block though, I suppose

Comment: The timer event will be raised every `interval` number of seconds, this prevents the `Elapsed` event from being raised multiple times at the same time: [Timer.Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: To make my problem more clear, if let's sat the method takes 59 seconds then it rests a second then starts over. If it takes let's say 159 seconds, it is allowed to run as long as it takes, after than it rest for 30 seconds(or I can just tell it to start right away again)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions depending on what you want.  Do you want to do work once a minute on the minute and always wait for the next minute?  Or do you want to run no more than once a minute but it's okay to "catch up" if you fall behind?

In other words, if processing takes 80 seconds then does the next work start immediately or wait until T=120?

The first is easier, but note that I haven't tested this and it's just a guideline:

```
AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
System.Timer(() => waitHandle.Set(), null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));

while (true)
{
  // Do stuff
  waitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

The second is just a bit harder.

```
ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent (false);
System.Timer(() => waitHandle.Set(), null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));

while (true)
{
  // Do stuff
  waitHandle.Reset();
  waitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```